# Length of the Root Node in xml C++

Tags: c++

When I get the length of "Node", I am getting the length as 1. When I get the

"subnode" length I am getting as 1 as well. How is it possible? How can I

differentiate both the nodes if it returns the same length.

```
<Node>
   <Subnode>xyz</Subnode>
</Node>
```

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr  pAttributeList = NULL;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr pNestedAttList = NULL;
pIdRootNode->get_childNodes(&pAttributeList);
for (int iAttIndex = 0; iAttIndex < pAttributeList->Getlength(); iAttIndex++)
{
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pCurrentNode = pAttributeList->Getitem(iAttIndex);
    int l = pCurrentNode->GetchildNodes()->Getlength();
    //on each node check whether it has any child nodes and process those nested child properties too.
    if (l > 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks correct. What values would you expect? Why would you expect to differentiate nodes by the number of children anyway?

Comment: I have to check whether each node contains any child node or not. If there are no child nodes then i need to print the value. So, till i find the leaf node i need to iterate this recursively.

Comment: When Node length is  greater 0 i.e., it has some childs, then iam calling the Recursive function to find if there are any childs for the next node. If the inner child returns length as 1 then it falls in recursive loop.

Comment: Expected Result is :                                                                                      the Length of Node is 1 since it has inner child <Subnode>                   The length of subnode is 0 since it doesnot have any childs inside it, but the value of the subnode is xyz.. So by this way i can differentiate the difference between both nodes. Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: @sam: I don't know with msxml2 but with other XML parsers, the content of `Subnode` is a "text node", so length of `Subnode` is 1. Try with an empty Subnode (`<Subnode/>`); it's length should be 0.

Comment: Yes with empty subnode the length will be 0 only. But i wont get such node and there is no use with such node.

Comment: Found ans. myself. After getting the length of subnode as 1, iterate one more time this time the length will be 0 and xyz is the #text node and its parent is <SubNode>. My problem got fixed.